# Uploading video to S3 bucket using Swift and AWS SDK

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am receiving the following error while uploading a 6 second video to my S3 bucket:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.)

This happens after my bar has reached 100% on the upload to AWS

Things I have tried:

1) Making sure my iphone was set to the correct timezone (and also setting it automatically"

2) I have opened my bucket permissions wider than I ever would normally, to ensure that its not an issue with the permissions everything is public read and write.

3)Put the user in a group that has full permissions to the S3 bucket

4) Attempted to get a more granular error logging, I seem to be unable to capture what I am looking for (my code returns that userInfo is incorrect)

```
 let errorInfo = err.userInfo["Error"] as? [String: Any]
    if errorInfo != nil {
        print("Found error in response. Details are:")
        for element in errorInfo! {
            print(">> \(element.key): \(element.value)")
        }
   }
```

5) I only have one region for selection which I illustrate below (someone had suggested that region can cause issues):

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

I don't know if this will be of any value, but this is the result of my task response:

```
task response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x281ac0d40> { URL: ..urlstuff } { Status Code: 404, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/xml"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 02 Jul 2019 06:28:13 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        AmazonS3
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "x-amz-id-2" =     (
        "stuff"
    );
    "x-amz-request-id" =     (
        stuff
    );
} }
Task request urlstuff
```

One thing that I have seen is that I am using a different object than most, which utlizes a key a secret :AWSStaticCredentialsProvider most of the tutorials I have seen suggest using :AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider

Comment: Hello Bob.  How do you obtain the access key and secret key ?  And how long is taking (should take) the upload ?  It sometimes happen that temporary credentials expire during a long, multi part, transfer, which might cause error like this. The 404 error in NSHTTPResponse indicates an authorization issue.  Does the upload work on small files ? (a 6 secs video is pretty small and should not trigger this, but I am just willing to confirm or not a few hypotheses)

Comment: Hello! I have the access and secret key loaded in appdelegate (they are set as strings) - the upload takes approximately 6-8 seconds. I agree with your thoughts on the multipart transfer, I saw one github case that was opened that the request needed to be broken down further. That will be my next course of action. Thank you.

Comment: i also turned on server side logging and object level logging, it doesn't seem to be returning much in the way of utility.

Comment: So, if access key and secret key hard hard coded, they are not temporary.  Temporary keys are typically valid for 15 min, so the issue you're observing is likely not a key expiration.  Let me dig further.  I assume you have all latest versions of SDK, correct ?

Comment: I just tested this (it requires amplify to setup the bucket) https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtility-Sample/Swift It works as expected.  So at least there is no systemic issue in the SDK :-)  Can you check this example to verify how different it is from your code ?

Comment: I didn’t set a version number in cocoa pods, so I assumed that it will pull down the latest versions.

Comment: Stil having this problem ?  Does the S3 sample code I posted above help ? Can you reproduce it in minimum app and share it on GitHub ?

Comment: So I was able to use the sample code and write to my S3 bucket (from my app) - I however wasn't able to get the AWSServiceConfiguration provider to work. I have git version that I can roll back to that i need to test with though - because I suspect the error that I was seeing was actually being cause by the filepath not being correct. Still need to verify that theory though.

Comment: Good to learn you're making progress bob.  Do not hesitate to share sample code to allow me to help further.